# Custom popup message

Tags: extjs

By calling `chart.setLoading(true)` such "Loading..." popup appears:

[image]

How can I show the same popup without ajax indicator and with another text?

Answer (score 2):

There is a LoadMask class, you can call via xtype.
[ExtJS4 LoadMask](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask)

Comment: use this function http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask-method-hide
to remove load indicator

Comment: I need to hide only animated loading indicator in my custom mask

Comment: I did not do this before, but you could try to remove the image of the animation with css for the given ID. ExtJS has DOM manipulation methods like jQuery. [DOM Manipulation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element)